# Adding object of various type to an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Im having the following objects in my class,

```
LatestRingtones latestRingtones;
MostDownloadedSongs mostDownloadedSongs;
LatestDialoges latestDialoges;
```

LatestRingtones, MostDownloadedSongs,LatestDialoges extends sugarrecord.

So, I have created an arraylist to store object of various types as follows,

```
public List<SugarRecord> streamingTrackList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I tried to add the latestRingtones as follows

```
streamingTrackList.add(latestRingtones);
```

but im getting an error like `List can not be applied to jsonarray`

How can i be able to convert the jsonarray to list and add it to streaming track or is there any ways through which I can add object of various types to streamingTrack?

Comment: How are you getting this `latestDialogeTen`? Is it a list or object? More code will be helpful to understand your situation.

Comment: What is the actual type of latestDialogeTen? How is it declared? How is it obtained?

Comment: Why are you trying to store a random assortment of things in one array?

Comment: Im trying to store entire object in a common arraylist. Later on I will access the arraylist to retrieve the song details that includes art url, song url etc...m

Comment: For a question about code not working we need a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org) (maybe not always, but I should say we do in this case). You may think it’s much work at first, but in the end I believe you’ll find it worthwhile.

Comment: All songs has got file name, art url, song url. Songs might be in Latest ringtones or Most downloaded songs etc..., when Latest Ringtones is clicked, array list has to be populated with latest songs.when Most downloaded songs list is clicked, array list has to be populated with most dowloaded songs. Later on I will access the array list if I need to play songs

Comment: You're asking a question about an error message you don't understand, related to some code. So, your question should contain the code causing the error, and the exact and complete error message you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ***latestRingtones*** is a json array **you can not add a JsonArray into ArrayList** . 
So simply convert you jsonarray in Object array using any know library (gson , simple json etc) and than add the objects into your ArrayList